Howto Generate TOC in Org Mode Documents
For Org Mode, I'm trying to generate a Table of Contents, but can't seem to make any headway. I've looked at the official documentation. Although I suspect this is just for exporting Org documents.
I've not found any direction on how to actually generate a Table of Contents with links that would appear in Github.
I've also explored snosov1/toc-org and alphapapa/org-make-toc. But their functions don't even generate malformed TOCs.
I was able to generate a TOC once with alphapapa/org-make-toc. But can't replicate the result when trying to generate.
Sometimes nothing happens. And sometimes running org-make-toc throws the message: user-error: Before first headline at position 213 in buffer SUNRA.org (source).
What am I missing?
Emacs: 29.4 (https://emacsformacosx.com)
